# Use Python Pandas to return the count using 2 conditions

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filter, conditional-statements

I have the following csv file (snippet)

```
GENDER  FULL_NAME            FIRST   MIDDLE    LAST
M       Sam Co               Sam               Co
F       Jen Hill            
M       Frank Hill Billy     Frank             Hill Billy
M       Phil Tori Vega       Phil    Tori      Vega 
M       Bob Smith-Oreiley    Bob               Smith-Oreiley
F       Mia
```

In my data, the FULL_NAME column is a concatenation of FIRST MIDDLE AND LAST and it is always populated regardless if the FIRST, MIDDLE or LAST names are empty due to missing data.

I want to count how many Females and Males have blank names (where FIRST MIDDLE LAST are all blank) OUTPUT:

```
F:2
M:0
```

And I want to count how many males and females have FIRST, MIDDLE OR LAST names populated. (where at least 1 column is populated)

```
F:0
M:4
```

this sort of thing is easily done on excel however my data is too large and it would be better to do this in python instead as I have many similar files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exist values are missing:

```
print (df)
  GENDER          FULL_NAME  FIRST MIDDLE           LAST
0      M             Sam Co    Sam     Co            NaN
1      F           Jen Hill    NaN    NaN            NaN
2      M   Frank Hill Billy  Frank    NaN     Hill Billy
3      M     Phil Tori Vega   Phil   Tori           Vega
4      M  Bob Smith-Oreiley    Bob    NaN  Smith-Oreiley
5      F                Mia    NaN    NaN            NaN

print (df.isna())
   GENDER  FULL_NAME  FIRST  MIDDLE   LAST
0   False      False  False   False   True
1   False      False   True    True   True
2   False      False  False    True  False
3   False      False  False   False  False
4   False      False  False    True  False
5   False      False   True    True   True
```

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with test if filtered columns has all missing values tested by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and for custom values pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
cols = ['FIRST', 'MIDDLE', 'LAST']

df = (pd.crosstab(df['GENDER'], 
                 np.where(df[cols].isna().all(axis=1),'miss','non miss'))
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None))

print (df)
   miss  non miss
F     2         0
M     0         4
```

If need new column for `GENDER`:

```
cols = ['FIRST', 'MIDDLE', 'LAST']

df = (pd.crosstab(df['GENDER'], 
                 np.where(df[cols].isna().all(axis=1),'miss','non miss'))
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index())

print (df)
  GENDER  miss  non miss
0      F     2         0
1      M     0         4
```

Comment: thank you for this I have tried it  on my pycharm however I am ONLY GETTING THE non miss output and not the miss one @jezrael

Comment: @Girl007 - Are missing values `NaN`s ? Or empty strings? If yes, then use `df[cols].eq('')` instead `df[cols].isna()`

Comment: ahh I see yes I did df = pd.read_csv("data.csv").fillna("")   please could you kindly tell me the difference ?

Comment: @Girl007 - I think the best is check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html).